# Multiple Prev/Next buttons for multiple horizontal scroll containers with same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a DOM with multiple horizontal scroll containers and prev next buttons. I'm not able to change the html so that's what I got.

```
<div class="scroll_container"></div>
<div class="prev_button_wrapper">
 <button class="prev_button"></div>
</div>
<div class="next_button_wrapper">
 <button class="next_button"></div>
</div>

<div class="scroll_container"></div>
<div class="prev_button_wrapper">
 <button class="prev_button"></div>
</div>
<div class="next_button_wrapper">
 <button class="next_button"></div>
</div>
...
```

So far I got this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 jQuery(".prev_button").click(
    function() {
        var thumbHolder = jQuery(".scroll_container");
        thumbHolder.scrollLeft(thumbHolder.scrollLeft() - 300);
    }
 );
 jQuery(".next_button").click(
    function() {
        var thumbHolder = jQuery(".scroll_container");
        thumbHolder.scrollLeft(thumbHolder.scrollLeft() + 300);
    }
 );
});
```

Of course the problem is, that the first prev and next buttons scroll all containers on the page. I already tried to use `closest()` but I couldn't get it work.I'm at a very basic level with Java/jQuery and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To make your jQuery code work for each arrangement of parchment compartments and their comparing prev/next buttons, you want to utilize crossing techniques like `nearest()` and `next()` to focus on the particular holders and buttons connected with one another. Here is the changed code that ought to work accurately:

```
<!-- First set of scroll -->
<div class="scroll_container"></div>
<div class="prev_button_wrapper">
  <button class="prev_button"></button>
</div>
<div class="next_button_wrapper">
  <button class="next_button"></button>
</div>

<!-- Second set of scroll -->
<div class="scroll_container"></div>
<div class="prev_button_wrapper">
  <button class="prev_button"></button>
</div>
<div class="next_button_wrapper">
  <button class="next_button"></button>
</div>

...
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".prev_button").click(function() {
    var container = jQuery(this).closest('.prev_button_wrapper').prev('.scroll_container');
    container.scrollLeft(container.scrollLeft() - 300);
  });

  jQuery(".next_button").click(function() {
    var container = jQuery(this).closest('.next_button_wrapper').prev('.scroll_container');
    container.scrollLeft(container.scrollLeft() + 300);
  });
});
```

With the changes above, when you click on a particular prev_button, it will view as the comparing `.scroll_container` component utilizing `closest('.prev_button_wrapper')` and afterward use `prev('.scroll_container')` to get the compartment that precedes the clicked button. Additionally, for the next_button, it will view as the comparing .scroll_container component utilizing `closest('.next_button_wrapper')` and afterward use `prev('.scroll_container')` to get the holder that precedes the next_button.

Along these lines, the snap occasions will focus on the right parchment compartment connected with each arrangement of prev/next buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because the `.scroll_container` isn't wrapped within the same parent as any individual `<button>` group, using `closest()` to find the relevant element will either fail – and simply not find the element, based on the selector passed to the method – or alternatively – depending on the selector... – find *all* `.scroll_container` elements.

This being the case, we're required to use a somewhat complex mix of `closest()`, `prevAll()`, `first()` and `find()`. This would – of course – be much easier if the HTML could be adjusted, even if only in the JavaScript/jQuery to wrap elements together.

Without that option, though, this is the best approach I could think of; there are explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// here we retrieve all <button> elements, and use the on() method to
// bind the anonymous function as the event-handler for those buttons
// that match the supplied selector list:
$('button').on('click', function() {
  // the clicked <button>:
  let btn = $(this),
    // the first ancestor of the clicked <button> that matches the
    // supplied CSS selector:
    parent = $(this).closest('div[class$="_wrapper"]'),
    // if the <button> has the class of 'prev_button', we
    // return -100 as the scrollDistance; otherwise - because we
    // restricted the event-handler to either '.prev_button' or
    // 'next_button', the distance will be 100:
    scrollDistance = btn.hasClass('prev_button') ? -100 : 100,
    // this would be easier if the <button> elements and the
    // scrolling element were all wrapped in the same element,
    // and distinct from the other elements; but here we navigate
    // from the ancestor element using prevAll() to find all
    // previous siblings that match the supplied CSS selector,
    // along with the first() method to retain only the first of
    // those siblings; in that element we use find() to find
    // the descendant child-element that is the :first-child;
    // in this demo that's the element we want to scroll, in your
    // case this may be a different element so bear that in mind:
    scrollElement = parent.prevAll('.scroll_container').first().find('> :first-child'),
    // we retrieve the current scroll position of the element to
    // scroll, using the scrollLeft() method with no argument,
    // which causes it to get - rather than set - the scrollLeft
    // position:
    currentScroll = scrollElement.scrollLeft();

  // we then use scrollLeft() with an argument, in order to
  // have it set the scrollLeft position, to a distance of
  // the currentScroll plus the scrollDistance:
  scrollElement.scrollLeft(currentScroll + scrollDistance);
});
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 2rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-block: 1rem;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  flex-basis: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.prev_button_wrapper,
.next_button_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll_container">
  <!-- I'm aware that you can't change your HTML, this is simply dummy content,
       replace with your real content in development/production: -->
  <ol>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
    <li>l</li>
    <li>m</li>
    <li>n</li>
    <li>o</li>
    <li>p</li>
    <li>q</li>
    <li>r</li>
    <li>s</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>u</li>
    <li>v</li>
    <li>w</li>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="prev_button_wrapper">
  <button class="prev_button">&laquo;</button>
</div>

<div class="next_button_wrapper">
  <button class="next_button">&raquo;</button>
</div>


<div class="scroll_container">

  <ol>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
    <li>l</li>
    <li>m</li>
    <li>n</li>
    <li>o</li>
    <li>p</li>
    <li>q</li>
    <li>r</li>
    <li>s</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>u</li>
    <li>v</li>
    <li>w</li>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="prev_button_wrapper">
  <button class="prev_button">&laquo;</button>
</div>

<div class="next_button_wrapper">
  <button class="next_button">&raquo;</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nb9kg0ct/).

References:

- [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest).
- [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find).
- [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first).
- [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass).
- [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on).
- [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll).
- [`scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft).